# Highlight arbitary cell boarders in grids in jupyter

Tags: jupyter, ipywidgets

I want to draw the following type of puzzle in Jupyter, which feature a grid where the boards of some cells are highlighted:

[image: Image of Aquarium Puzzle]

I would like users to be able to click on cells, and then respond.

I could not find a grid system which let me control the boards of each cell -- I could of course produce raw HTML, but I was wondering if there was a nicer alternative?